# Enforcing Order of Operations on Dimension Expressions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfmath

I'm trying to make a tikz drawing using the component lengths as macros so I can easily adjust things and have changes propagate. That works, but when I try to use division to draw lines at even intervals on a macro-defined width, I get problems. I think it is because the fractions are being applied to only the first value in the tableWidth command, as it is just a dumb substitution, rather than combining the values in the command before inserting it into the body.

How can I force latex to evaluate math on a dimension before I apply other operations to it? Are there other packages I should be using to do this? I have googled around and found things relating to dimexpr and others but can't make sense of it or make it work for my context.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand{\positionRad}{14mm}
\newcommand{\positionSpacing}{32mm}

\newcommand{\iconSize}{12mm}

\newcommand{\tableHeight}{20mm}
\newcommand{\tablePad}{6mm}

\newcommand{\tablePositionSep}{\positionRad+8mm}


\newcommand{\tableWidth}{4*\positionSpacing + \positionRad}


\graphicspath{{../icons/}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
\draw (\positionSpacing, \tablePositionSep+\tableHeight) circle (\positionRad) node{\LARGE1};
\draw (2*\positionSpacing, \tablePositionSep+\tableHeight) circle (\positionRad) node{\LARGE2};
\draw (3*\positionSpacing, \tablePositionSep+\tableHeight) circle (\positionRad) node{\LARGE3};
\draw (4*\positionSpacing, \tablePositionSep+\tableHeight) circle (\positionRad) node{\LARGE4};

\draw (\positionSpacing-\positionRad,\tablePad) rectangle (\tableWidth,\tablePad+\tableHeight);
\draw (1/6*\tableWidth,\tablePad) -- (1/6*\tableWidth,\tablePad+\tableHeight);
\draw (1/3*\tableWidth,\tablePad) -- (1/3*\tableWidth,\tablePad+\tableHeight);
\draw (1/2*\tableWidth,\tablePad) -- (1/2*\tableWidth,\tablePad+\tableHeight);
\draw (5/6*\tableWidth,\tablePad) -- (5/6*\tableWidth,\tablePad+\tableHeight);
\draw (2/3*\tableWidth,\tablePad) -- (2/3*\tableWidth,\tablePad+\tableHeight);

\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand{\tablePositionSep}{\the\dimexpr\positionRad+8mm} \newcommand{\tableWidth}{\the\dimexpr4*\positionSpacing + \positionRad}`? I think that you should remove things of the type  `\includegraphics[width=\iconSize]{inf.png}` because others won't have the png file, and add an appropriate `\documentclass` so that others can run your file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it is because the fractions are being applied to only the first value in the tableWidth command, as it is just a dumb substitution, rather than combining the values in the command before inserting it into the body.

Correct, it is dumb substitution.

With

```
\newcommand\foo{1+2}
```

the expresion `3*\foo` becomes `3*1+2` when PGFmath evaluates it.

You would need `3*(\foo)`, though, in your case I'd just add the parentheses directly to `\foo`:

```
\newcommand\foo{(1+2)}
```

then `3*\foo` (→ `3*(1+2)`) is evaluated correctly.

However, since the TikZ parser is greedy when it parses a coordinate, these expressions need to be protected from it by enclosing the components in `{…}`.

There's also an option to use PGFmath functions defined by `declare function`, e.g.

```
declare function={
  tablePositionSep=\positionSpacing+8mm;
  tableWidth=4*\positionSpacing+\positionRad;
}
```

but mixing that with dimension units can make it messy when used inside TikZ … or I messed something up by converting your picture.

### Code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\newcommand{\positionRad}    {14mm}
\newcommand{\positionSpacing}{32mm}
\newcommand{\iconSize}       {12mm}
\newcommand{\tableHeight}    {20mm}
\newcommand{\tablePad}        {6mm}

\newcommand{\tablePositionSep}{(\positionRad+8mm)}
\newcommand{\tableWidth}      {(4*\positionSpacing + \positionRad)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=\positionRad]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw (  \positionSpacing, {\tablePositionSep+\tableHeight}) circle [] node{\LARGE1};
\draw (2*\positionSpacing, {\tablePositionSep+\tableHeight}) circle [] node{\LARGE2};
\draw (3*\positionSpacing, {\tablePositionSep+\tableHeight}) circle [] node{\LARGE3};
\draw (4*\positionSpacing, {\tablePositionSep+\tableHeight}) circle [] node{\LARGE4};

\draw (\positionSpacing-\positionRad, \tablePad) rectangle ({\tableWidth}, \tablePad+\tableHeight);
\draw ({1/6*\tableWidth}, \tablePad) -- ({1/6*\tableWidth}, \tablePad+\tableHeight);
\draw ({1/3*\tableWidth}, \tablePad) -- ({1/3*\tableWidth}, \tablePad+\tableHeight);
\draw ({1/2*\tableWidth}, \tablePad) -- ({1/2*\tableWidth}, \tablePad+\tableHeight);
\draw ({5/6*\tableWidth}, \tablePad) -- ({5/6*\tableWidth}, \tablePad+\tableHeight);
\draw ({2/3*\tableWidth}, \tablePad) -- ({2/3*\tableWidth}, \tablePad+\tableHeight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```