# What math functions can be used in plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

The below code shows that the graph of function x<sup>n</sup> is incorrect when `n` is even (unless typed as `\x*\x` instead of `\x^2`). So I'm curious what math formulas are allowed in `plot` to make sure that it's correct?

Also I've got an error when trying to use brackets: `\draw plot (\x,\x*(1-\x));`.
`Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?` What is the syntax for math brackets or it's not allowed at all for `plot` function's argument?

The manual [pgfmanual v3.1.10](https://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) on page 344 gives examples with functions sin(\x) and 0.05*exp(\x). Is there a comprehensive list of math functions, which are valid for latex function `plot`? For example, is it possible to draw function `(x+1/3)^(1/x)` on interval `[1,4]` using `plot` (i. e. without using `pgfplots` or `gnuplot`)?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-1:1]
\draw plot (\x,\x*\x);
\draw[red, dashed] plot (\x,\x^2);
\draw[blue] plot (\x,\x*\x*\x*\x);
\draw[green, dashed] plot (\x,\x^4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT.
After reading pgfmanual (p. 1034) I realized that it's safer to use `pow(\x,2)` instead of `\x^2` (especially for some complicated functions). I mean it might be even safer option than `(\x)^2`.

Comment: You are asking two questions in one. Maybe you should edit your title or split it into two separate questions (I'm writing an answer nonetheless).

Comment: See chapter 94 Mathematical Expressions of the pgfmanual.

Comment: Concerning `)` in a coordinate expression: [You need to protect them.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662447) (Similar how you have to protect a `]` in an optional argment.) Regarding `\x^4` getting into the negative, see [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662462). PGFmath is just dumbly expanding `\x` before it can be considered a single thing. You will need to use`(\x)^4`.

Comment: This is just the orders of operation in mathematics, which we remember by PEMDAS: parentheses, exponentiation, multiplication/division (left to right), addition/subtraction (left to right). - is a unary operator which multiplies the result by -1. So -3^2 means (-1)*(3)^2 and then exponentiation comes first, so (-1)*9=-9. Putting (-3)^2 is ((-1)*(3))^2 which is (-3)^2=9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the first question: The list of functions understood by the pgfmath engine is listed in section [94.3 Syntax for Mathematical Expressions: Functions](https://tikz.dev/math-parsing) of the pgfmanual.

---

As for your problem with `\x^2`: It appears that TikZ first expands `\x` and then parses the `^2`. For example with `\x=-3` TikZ would see `-3^2`, which a math parser typically understands as `-(3^2)`. Other programming languages typically square the value of `x` directly, without first expanding it into `-3`, so that is where the confusion comes from.

Edit: There is a related [bug report showing similar behavior for division](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1084).

You can fix this by putting parentheses around `\x`, but then you need braces around the `Y` part of your coordinate: `\draw[red, dashed] plot (\x,{(\x)^2});`

[image: Picture showing 4 curves]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-1:1]
\draw plot (\x,\x*\x);
\draw[red, dashed] plot (\x,{(\x)^2});
\draw[blue] plot (\x,\x*\x*\x*\x);
\draw[green, dashed] plot (\x,{(\x)^4});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: PGFMath's first step is to expand everything. It will never consider any macros to be single thing. [Google also thinks `-3^4` = `-(3^4)`](https://www.google.com/search?q=-3^4). So does [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-3%5E4).

Comment: @Fritz Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed to know! Finally, this `\draw plot (\x,{\x*(1-\x)});` is working!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thanks, I stand corrected and have edited my answer accordingly. Python also calculates `-3**2` as `-9`.

Comment: @Fritz It's a tricky thing (and a common one to trip over). `\x` looks like a variable but it isn't. 

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The `non variable` part explains it, thanks.