# How to use expression of self-defined constant in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I use the self-defined constant directly (`\epsi`), it works. But when I use the expression (`\supp`), it does not work.

The minimal example is as follows.

```
\documentclass[notitlepage, 12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,intersections,through,backgrounds} 
\usepackage[capposition=bottom]{floatrow}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=6,yscale=6]

\def\epsi{0.1};
\def\aa{0.6};
\def\supp{(\epsi)/(\epsi+2*\aa-1)};

\draw [<->] (0,1.1)--(0,0)--(1.1,0);

%\draw (\epsi,0)--(1,1);
\draw (\supp,0)--(1,1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\draw ({\supp},0)--(1,1);`. [A662447](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662447), [A662462](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662462) and related. You can do also `\pgfmathsetmacro\supp{(\epsi)/(\epsi+2*\aa-1)}` which will evaluate the formula at that point and store the result in `\supp` which can then be used the same as `\epsi`.

Comment: You can also `declare function = {supp = (\epsi)/(\epsi+2*\aa-1);}` and then simply use `epsi`. That way you have defined a PGFmath function that, similar to your `\supp`, gets only evaluated when you use it (and thus changes with `\epsi` and `\aa`. Nothing wrong with using a macro, it's just one of many ways to use values and in this case avoid your original problem.