# A bug in self-defined constant in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[notitlepage, 12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsaddr, amssymb, graphicx, dsfont,}  
  \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
 \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage[capposition=bottom]{floatrow}
 \usepackage{float}


  \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[H]
 \centering

 \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=8,yscale=8]

  \def\epsi{0.05};
  \def\aa{0.6};

 \def\suppd{0};
 \def\suppe{(1-\aa)/(\aa)};

 \def\pd{1-\aa};

 \def\yd{\pd*(\suppe-\suppd)};

 \draw [<->] (0,1.1)--(0,0)--(1.1,0);


  \draw (0,{(1-\aa)^2/\aa})--(1,{\yd});

   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{figure}


    \end{document}
```

The algebra indicates \yd should be $\frac{(1-\alpha)^2}{\alpha}$, but the graph I draw suggests it is not the case (the line is not horizontal). I was wondering what is going wrong.

Comment: probably unrelated but using `\def` to over-write core latex commands with no warning is somewhat risky

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Which one are you referring to? I don't know whether any of them is pre-defined in latex.

Comment: that is why `\def` should not be used, a latex definition such as `\newcommand` would have alerted you. (`\aa`)

Comment: `\yd` will expand to`{1-\aa*(\suppe-\suppd)}`. You need to define `\pd` to be `(1-\aa)` or enclose `\pd` with parentheses inside the defintion of `\yd`. TeX macros aren't variables. It's just [“dumb” substitution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662462).

Comment: Alternatively, do `\pgfmathsetmacro\pd{1-\aa}` which will evaluate `1-\aa` and store the result in `\pd`. (Though, just like `\def` PGFMath won't check whether the macro is already defined.) Or define your own [PGFMath functions](https://tikz.dev/math-algorithms#pgf/declare:function).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Aha, that is the bug! Thanks!